# Ruby Version help

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ok, currently I'm using Go Daddy as a host. They provide Rails version 2.3.2 so I'm assuming I can't use rails 3 on their server. I'm willing to remove Rails 3 and install a previous version if need be but i'm not sure which version I need and whether I could get a windows self installer as with rails 3?

Comment: This question is confusing me.  Here are a couple of ways to improve the intent of your question: 1) You should use "their" (as in, "their Rails version is 2.3.2") instead of "there" ("Have you ever been there?"). 2) Break your question up into multiple sentences and use proper capitalization (e.g. "Ok currently i'm using Go Daddy as a host there Rails version 2.3.2. So, i'm asuming...").

Comment: don't know what is confusing you its all there. how hard is it to understand i need to know what ver to use?

Comment: if all your worried about is my grammar then don't bother answering my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using ruby version 1.8.7 available here: http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/73719/rubyinstaller-1.8.7-p330.exe

Instructions on installing Rails on windows are here http://allaboutruby.wordpress.com/2009/07/20/installing-rails-on-windows-3-years-later/

Comment: thx much nice to see an answer that use full and not a cut on my grammar